# Lambda SDK for JavaScriptのV3移行に伴いコードを変更したがエラーで正常に動作しない

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

下記のコードをV2からv3に変更しましたが、正常に動作しません。
エラーは下記となります。
原因が分かるようでしたら、ご教示いただけますでしょうか？

### 出力されたエラー

```
2023-10-19T00:29:03.610Z    b5e27243-cafd-4693-9c94-714fb04b21ff    ERROR   Error scanning DynamoDB table: Error: Unsupported type passed: PhoneNumber
    at convertToNative (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb/dist-cjs/convertToNative.js:29:27)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb/dist-cjs/convertToNative.js:62:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at convertMap (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb/dist-cjs/convertToNative.js:60:58)
    at convertToNative (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb/dist-cjs/convertToNative.js:21:28)
    at unmarshall (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb/dist-cjs/unmarshall.js:5:77)
    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:20:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

### aws-sdk v2を用いたコード

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "ap-northeast-1" });
const tableName = 'PhoneTable';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // 発信者番号
    const phone = event.Details.ContactData.CustomerEndpoint.Address;
    // DynamoDBの一覧取得
    const db = await DynamoDB.scan({TableName: tableName}).promise();
    // 発信者番号が一覧に存在するかどうかの確認
    const result = db.Items.some( item => {
        return (item.PhoneNumber == phone);
    });
    return { result : result };
};
```

### aws-sdk v3を用いたコード

```js
import { DynamoDBClient, ScanCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { marshall, unmarshall } from "@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb";
const region = "ap-northeast-1";
const tableName = 'PhoneTable';

const dynamodbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: region });

export const handler = async (event) => {
    // 発信者番号
    const phone = event.Details.ContactData.CustomerEndpoint.Address;
    
    // DynamoDBの一覧取得
    const scanParams = {
        TableName: tableName,
    };

    try {
        const scanCommand = new ScanCommand(scanParams);
        const data = await dynamodbClient.send(scanCommand);
        const db = unmarshall(data.Items);

        // 発信者番号が一覧に存在するかどうかの確認
        const result = db.some(item => {
            return (item.PhoneNumber === phone);
        });

        return { result: result };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error scanning DynamoDB table:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Comment: [削除された直近の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/96020) とほぼ同じ内容に見えます。回答がつかなくてもどかしい気持ちも分かりますが、まずは「質問の編集」で情報を追加することを優先してください。 / 元の投稿ではコメントのやり取りも発生しているので、安易に削除してしまうのは不親切だと思います。

Comment: PhoneNumberがサポートされていないとエラーが発生します。
V2ではサポートされていたけど、V3ではサポと対象外ということでしょうか？